# Jasmine/Karma branch not covered when using null assertion

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to improve my code coverage in Jasmine/Karma but have been hitting a branch coverage roadblock in cases where I'm using null assertion in my code.

For instance:

```
this.parentCarrierForm.controls.carrierName.setValue(
  this.carrier?.carrierName,
);
```

The testrunner coverage report shows:

[image: testrunner coverage image]

Hovering over the highlighted portion raises the `branch not covered` tooltip and dings the branch coverage percentage.

In the example above, I am trying to use null assertion into a FormControl, the same result can be found when assigning the value to a variable such as `const myVariable = String(this.carrier?.carrierName)`. The `branch not covered` coverage error is still present.

What is the best way to get Jasmine/Karma to stop complaining about null assertion?

Answer (score 0):

That is trying to tell you that you have a test that has an undefined `this.carrier` and it tested fine.

However you have zero tests where you have assigned a value to `this.carrier`.

A test like the following would help your coverage.

```
it('carrier name gets set correctly', () => {
 // however you're setting up the component, hopefully in the beforeEach
 const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
 const component = fixture.componentInstance;

 // set the carrier to something
 component.carrier = new Carrier();
 component.carrier.carrierName = 'meow';
 fixture.detectChanges(); // or whatever calls your code that you want covered

 // assert that the form value has been set appropriately
 const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector));
 expect(element.nativeElement.value.trim()).toBe('meow');
});
```

Remember that if you don't put in that assert your test coverage only indicates that the code doesn't throw null exceptions, it won't guarantee that the code does what you want it to.